# How to "translate" a complex query to Laravel Query Builder?

Tags: php, laravel-5.4, laravel-query-builder

I have following complex query and would like to use it in Laravel. But until now I had no success. Maybe one of you could show how to "translate" it to the query builder of Laravel.

Here the original query that in Workbench works well:

```
select * from lemma l 
inner join etymology e on l.id=e.lemma_id_fk 
inner join gloss g on e.id = g.etymology_id 
inner join wold_meanings w on g.gloss=w.meaning
where g.gloss like '%flower%' #paper, ocean, etc.
limit 100;
```

Than I tried the following:

```
  $results = DB::table('lemma')
  ->join('etymology', 'lemma.id', '=', 'etymology.lemma_id_fk')
  ->join('gloss', 'etymology.id', '=', 'gloss.etymology_id')
  ->join('wold_meanings', 'gloss.gloss', '=', 'wold_meanings.meaning')
  ->select(DB::raw('lemma.*'))
  ->where('gloss.gloss', 'like', '%flower%')
  ->get();
```

and also:

```
  $results = DB::table('lemma')
  ->select(DB::raw("select * from lemma l 
  inner join etymology e on l.id=e.lemma_id_fk 
  inner join gloss g on e.id = g.etymology_id 
  inner join wold_meanings w on g.gloss=w.meaning
  where g.gloss like '%flower%'
  limit 1"));
```

and this too:

```
  $results = DB::raw("select * from lemma l 
  inner join etymology e on l.id=e.lemma_id_fk 
  inner join gloss g on e.id = g.etymology_id 
  inner join wold_meanings w on g.gloss=w.meaning
  where g.gloss like '%flower%'
  limit 100");
```

But I had absolutely no succes... :-(

Anyone to show me the right way? I'm using Laravel 5.4.

**== EDIT #1 ==**

Here the view where the results should be shown:

```
        <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover table-responsive table-striped" id="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>id</th>
                    <th>lemma_id</th>
                    <th>headword</th>
                    <th>lemma</th>
                    <th>pos</th>
                    <th>gender</th>
                    <th>language</th>
                    <th>origin_family</th>
                    <th>origin</th>
                    <th>short_path</th>
                    <th>origin_path</th>
                    <th>etymology_text</th>
                    <th>first_use</th>
                    <th>lang</th>
                    <th>pageid</th>
                    <th>term</th>
                    <th>non_latin_script</th>
                    <th>lang_2</th>
                    <th>gloss</th>
                    <th>sequence</th>
                    <th>lemma_id_fk</th>
                    <th>derivatives_id</th>
                    <th>etymology_id</th>
                    <th>meaning</th>
                    <th>semantic_category</th>
                    <th>semantic_field</th>
                    <th>simplicity_score</th>
                    <th>age_score</th>
                    <th>borrowed_score</th>
                    <th>description</th>
                    <th>typical_context</th>
                    <th>representation</th>
                    <th>sub_code</th>
                </tr>               
            </thead>

            <tbody>
            @foreach($results as $result)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{$result->id}}</td>
                    <td>{{$result->lemma_id}}</td>
                    <td>{{$result->headword}}</td>
                    <td>{{$result->lemma}}</td>
                    <td>{{$result->pos}}</td>
                    <td>{{$result->gender}}</td>
                    <td>{{$result->language}}</td>
                    <td>{{$result->origin_family}}</td>
                    <td>{{$result->origin}}</td>
                    <td>{{$result->short_path}}</td>
                    <td>{{$result->origin_path}}</td>
                    <td>{{$result->etymology_text}}</td>
                    <td>{{$result->first_use}}</td>
                    <td>{{$result->lang}}</td>
                    <td>{{$result->pageid}}</td>
                    <td>{{$result->term}}</td>
                    <td>{{$result->non_latin_script}}</td>
                    <td>{{$result->lang_2}}</td>
                    <td>{{$result->gloss}}</td>
                    <td>{{$result->sequence}}</td>
                    <td>{{$result->lemma_id_fk}}</td>
                    <td>{{$result->derivatives_id}}</td>
                    <td>{{$result->etymology_id}}</td>
                    <td>{{$result->meaning}}</td>
                    <td>{{$result->semantic_category}}</td>
                    <td>{{$result->semantic_field}}</td>
                    <td>{{$result->simplicity_score}}</td>
                    <td>{{$result->age_score}}</td>
                    <td>{{$result->borrowed_score}}</td>
                    <td>{{$result->description}}</td>
                    <td>{{$result->typical_context}}</td>
                    <td>{{$result->representation}}</td>
                    <td>{{$result->sub_code}}</td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

== EDIT #2 ==

Just did some other tests here and realised that when using

```
  $results = DB::table('lemma')
  ->join('etymology', 'lemma.id', '=', 'etymology.lemma_id_fk')
  ->join('gloss', 'etymology.id', '=', 'gloss.etymology_id')
  ->join('wold_meanings', 'gloss.gloss', '=', 'wold_meanings.meaning')
  ->select(DB::raw('lemma.*'))
  ->where('gloss.gloss', 'like', '%flower%')
  ->get();
```

it gives me the result only from the table lemma, i.e., it ignores the joins. So I receive results in the table of the view from `<td>{{$result->id}}</td>` until `<td>{{$result->pageid}}</td>` but not the rest.

Comment: Any error or you are getting incorrect results?

Comment: The last one definitely should work, since it's the same raw query. What are you getting in `$result/$results` variable and what are you expecting?

Comment: @MayankPandeyz neither errors nor incorrect results... I my view I just see the thead of the table, while the results should appear into the tbody. And nothing in the console as well.

Comment: @GustavoStraube I'm getting nothing in the variable. I expect many results inside a foreach into the view. I will edit the question and show the view part.

Comment: I mean, what do you get from `var_dump($results);`? Is it `null` or something else?

Comment: About your edit #2, I guess if you remove the `select( ... )` part, you'll get what you want.

Comment: @GustavoStraube without select(...) it worked! Now I'll take a look to understand better how such a complex query should be transpose into Laravel's query build. How can I mark this as the right answer? Muito obrigado, me ajudou muito!

Comment: @AloysiadeArgenteuil added that as an answer. Now you can accept/upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the call to `select()` from the chain will make it work.

The `select` method represents the `SELECT` part of a query. This way, writing the following:

```
->select(DB::raw('lemma.*'))
```

It's the same as:

```
SELECT lemma.* FROM ...
```

In other words, you're only selecting the columns from `lemma` table.

However, since you want to also select the columns from other tables, omitting that part of your chain will make the Query Builder fallback to its default behavior, which is the same as:

```
SELECT * FROM ...
```

If you want to be explicit about what you're selecting, doing this will achieve the same:

```
->select('*')
```